# Exceeding the maximum number of row when exporting the SSRS report to Excel

Tags: reporting-services

When I try to export an SSRS report to Excel, I get this error about exceeding the maximum possible number of rows. Is there any way to fix this problem?

> Reporting Services Error:
>   Excel Rendering Extension: Number of rows exceeds the maximum possible in a worksheet of this version. Rows requested: 2181149. Maximum rows: 1048575. (rrRenderingError)
>   Excel Rendering Extension: Number of rows exceeds the maximum possible in a worksheet of this version. Rows requested: 2181149. Maximum rows: 1048575.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you can export to CSV.  Still won't load all in excel, but you'd have your data for using elsewhere.  Why do you need so much in an xls file?

Answer (score 0):

This is a technical limitation with Excel, to the best of my knowledge the only ways to work around this will significantly degrade the usefulness of the spreadsheet.

I would say that when you get to the point where you have to start thinking about maxing out Excel, you should definitely look at loading into a database at the destination via a pipeline. Alternatively, you can use other formats (such as CSV or TXT) that do not have row limits.

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely need it in an excel format from experience dealing with large excel files. I suggest simplifying the stored procedure or script you are calling for this report (if possible).

Adding a date range (if date field exists in data set) and breaking this up into parts. 
or I normally run the script in SQL window copy out maybe 500,000 rows at a time into separate excel files.

Just a suggesting could be a better way or alternately a different file format as previously suggested.